# OpenCV cross platform compilation on Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, cross-platform

I'm writing an object tracking program in OpenCV to run on the Raspberry Pi. I found out about the cross platform compilation in VS Community 2017. I created a new project, pasted my previously working code to it, added opencv folders to the project properties. However, it won't build. 
Build Output:

`pastebin.com/nfeTBvtd`

Any solutions? I'm a novice and kinda like IntelliSense, so I'd prefer VS over other editors. All help is appreciated nonetheless.

Update: What I did with the project properties:

- Under C/C++ -> General: Add opencv "include" folder to "Additional Include Directories"
- Under Linker -> General: Add opencv "lib" folder to "Additional Library Directories"
- Under Linker -> Input: Add opencv330d.lib to "Additional Dependencies"

All the above steps are from many YT tutorials I watched

Comment: Can you update your question with what you did in the project properties?

Comment: Sure. I've updated it

Comment: Make sure that you have added the correct opencv include folder: 'YOUR_PATH\opencv-3.3.0\opencv\build\include'. Choose option 'All configurations' under project properties (only for include folders). You need to fill the lib folders and input dependencies for all platforms and configurations that you want to build.

Comment: I chose "All configurations" and added the include folder. Now it compiled successfully but the linking process failed:
g++: error: opencv_world330.lib: No such file or directory

Comment: check the additional library directories part.... and make sure you find the .lib file. Also, remember that in this case you may want to use the debug one for debug (there is a d in the name of the .lib). You can also try the nugget packages... usually is easier if you do not need special modules.

Comment: The problem, I think, is that the VS linking process doesn't apply to Linux. On Windows if I do all the above steps in runs normally. On Linux if I call g++ with $(pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv) it runs normally too. However, VS did create .o files in the Raspberry. Can I somehow convert them into an executable? There are 3 .o files corresponding to 3 cpp files I have in my project